# Can't attach files with capybara_webkit driver, but i can with selenium driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to attach some files to an input area

```
 page.attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/picture.JPG'))
```

When I'm using `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium`everything is working fine, but i only use selenium to have a vision of the result. I need to use `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`, and when I'm doing it, I'm getting the error

```
Failure/Error: page.attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/picture.JPG')) 

 Capybara::Webkit::ClickFailed:
   Failed to click element /html/body/div[2]... because of overlapping element /html/body/div[2]...div[3]/em at position 255, 653;
```

Is there a specific reason this overlapping element is making the test fails only with `capybara_webkit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a specific reason this overlapping element is making the test
>   fails only with capybara_webkit?

Yeah, `capybara-webkit` is just more honest. It allows you to interact only with really visible elements. It seems your file input isn't visible or hidden, may be only part of it is hidden.

The usual solution in tests is just to make it (element) visible, for example by evaluating of javascript and updating css properties of this HTML element.

Comment: Ok, now I made the element visible. The problem is that the pictures are not uploading well, and not in the right field. This is what it's happening (I used `page.save_screenshot`): http://s3.postimg.org/t1jhpecxf/Screenshot_2015_11_30_a_las_16_48_23.png

Comment: @fabersky, I cannot say anything confidently without you form code and the test code. To which field image is attached instead of `image`? Please ensure you have only one HTML element with locator `image`

Comment: I just added a question with my code, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022916/attach-file-isnt-working-the-right-way-with-capybara-webkit