# attach_file isn't working the right way with capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to attach some files to this input:

```
<input type="file" name="image" multiple="" accept="image/*">
```

My code, that is working when I use `selenium` driver, is:

```
attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/pic1.JPG'))
attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/pic2.JPG'))
attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/pic3.JPG'))
```

The problems come when I use `capybara-webkit`: as the input is hidden and some elements overlaps it, I need to change some css properties:

```
page.execute_script("$('input[name=image]').css('opacity','1')")
page.execute_script("$('input[name=image]').css('position','fixed')")
page.execute_script("$('input[name=image]').css('top','620px')")
```

And even if the test passes, the pictures aren't uploading the right way. If I use `page.save_screenshot('after_upload.png')` to see what's happening:

Expected result (and result when using `selenium` driver) -> [image]

Actual result when using `capybara-webkit` -> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a "fix": put a `sleep(3)` after each image upload!

Comment: You shouldn't use sleep(3) but rather check for something that changes on the page when the new image completes uploading -- so if a new img element with the class uploaded is added something like  expect(page).to have_selector('img.uploadeded', count: 1)   or whatever.  That way Capybara only waits as long as necessary for the action to complete

Comment: Yes you are right, Tom. i will improve the test but for the moment I found a "fix". Is there any way to check if a button is enabled and clickable? Because before the photos upload, the "send photos" button is disabled, and after the photos upload it is enabled, so I could replace the `sleep(3)`checking this element.

Comment: If it is actually an html button element and is disabled with the disabled attribute then capybara won't find it until it becomes enabled -  ie. expect(page).to have_button('upload')   or  click_button('upload') will wait until the button is enabled before returning or clicking-- of course if it's being disabled via some other means that you'll need to come up with your own selector.  Also note that if that runs before the JS has actually disabled the button there would be an issue too.

Comment: you can use `disabled` option for finding the button (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afind_button). anyway you can always use something like `wait_until` helper (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara)

Comment: as mentioned, sleep is not the way, use build-in-like method have_selector, you can even change default wait time of it ;)